# Customizing Parse Login View in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, ios8, facebook-login

According to the documentation here https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views I could add the default Facebook login button to a PFLoginViewController. In Objective-C, the code is

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
[logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];
```

I'm having trouble translating this to Swift. Currently I have:

```
var loginVC = PFLogInViewController()
loginVC.fields = PFLogInFieldsDefault | PFLogInFieldsFacebook
```

The error I'm getting is PFLoginFields is not convertible to Bool. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do it by myself. To set the fields on the PFLogInViewController you have to set the fields like this:

`loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields(PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword.rawValue | PFLogInFields.LogInButton.rawValue)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var logInController = PFLogInViewController()
    logInController.delegate = self
    logInController.fields = PFLogInFields.Facebook | PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
loginVC.fields = PFLogInFields(PFLogInFieldsDefault.value | PFLogInFieldsFacebook.value)
```

found in Creators-iOS Project on Github:
https://github.com/ShiftCreatorSpace/Creators-iOS/blob/master/creators/LoginViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

When just giving two arguments for `valueA | valueB`, Swift(/Parse?) will interpret it as a bitwise OR operator, returning a boolean value. However, if you add more values (`valueA | valueB | valueC …`) it will be properly interpreted.